# django, css working but js not working

Tags: css, django

here my settings.py,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
    )
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and this is my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/docs.min.js' %}" ></script>
```

please help!!

Comment: Why are you loading your two different JavaScript files differently?

Comment: @Celeo thanks for the editing anyway!

Comment: How are you serving your CSS then, if that's working?

Comment: @DanielRoseman css working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need jquery for bootstrap, also:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src='/static/js/bootstrap.min.js' type="text/javascript">
```

If you have STATIC_URL in context you also need to add a slash "/",

Comment: is your js folder inside of static_dirs or static?

Comment: the path is static/static_dirs/js

Comment: So to clarify your network loading debug shows 404s for the javascript?

Comment: Do you have jquery? That is a requirement for bootstrap

Comment: yes, it is be installed and also added to the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py...its really frustrating

Comment: Jquery is a javascript library. Show your installed apps

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'articles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'django_markdown',
    'jquery',

]

Comment: You're not rendering jquery to the page above bootstrap.js is all. <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}></script>